# How can I prompt a user in Java to input a day of the week with the days in an enum output the response I want

Tags: java

I'm learning java and I got stuck at a question where I need to enter the days of the week into an enum.  I then need to put several responses into a switch case statement and have a user enter the day of the week into a JOptionPane and get the program to output the appropriate response.

This is my Enum:

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY; 
}
```

This is my attempt at getting the correct response:

```
public class enumDayMood {
    Day day;
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the day of the week.");
    }
    
    public void telDayMood(){
        
        Day day = Day.MONDAY;
        
        switch(day){
            case MONDAY:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Mondays are bad.");
                break;
            case FRIDAY:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Fridays are better.");
                break;
            case SATURDAY: case SUNDAY:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Weekends are best");
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Midweek days are so-so.");
                break;
        }
    }
    
}
```

I was able to output every day of the week individually but I can't seem to get the user input to work.  I've tried multiple methods but none seem to work.

Comment: `Day.valueOf(day)`?

Comment: That seems to work but now my JOptionPane isn't popping up for the responses

Comment: By the way, Java does provide an enum, [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using method [showOptionDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) rather than `showInputDialog`. Make each day of the week an option. Then the user just needs to click on the relevant button and that would save him some work, no? Consider the following:

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WeekDays {
    public enum Day {
        SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                                                 "Enter the day of the week.",
                                                 "Moody",
                                                 JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                                                 JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                                 null,
                                                 Day.values(),
                                                 Day.MONDAY);
        Day selection = Day.values()[index];
        switch (selection) {
            case MONDAY:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Mondays are bad.");
                break;
            case FRIDAY:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Fridays are better.");
                break;
            case SATURDAY: case SUNDAY:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Weekends are best");
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Midweek days are so-so.");
                break;
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks when I run it.

[image: screen capture of running app]

Comment: Okay sorry for the late reply, but thanks so much dude that's actually pretty cool.